# Recorriendo un diccionarios de diccionarios para obtener un valor

Tags: python, diccionarios

Estoy estancado en esta tarea que tengo, debo recorrer este conjunto de datos:

```
products = {
    "mobiles": {
        "Apple": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "iPhone 7",
                "price": 300
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "iPhone 8",
                "price": 350
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "iPhone Xr",
                "price": 450
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "iPhone Xs",
                "price": 460
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "iPhone 11",
                "price": 900
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "iPhone 12",
                "price": 1100
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "iPhone 13",
                "price": 1300
            },
        ],
        "Samsung": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy Beam",
                "price": 150
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S6",
                "price": 200
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S7",
                "price": 300
            },
        ],
        "Xiaomi": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8",
                "price": 250
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro",
                "price": 300
            },
        ]
    },
    "laptops": {
        "DELL": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Dell Inspiron 15",
                "price": 600
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Dell Latitude 14",
                "price": 650
            },
        ],
        "MAC": [
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "MacBook Pro 13",
                "price": 900
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "MacBook M1",
                "price": 1500
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

Al final para obtener los datos de cada uno de los productos y con ello hacer un pequeño menú interactivo que sea fácil de entender para un usuario.

Solo necesito saber como descomponer este diccionario de diccionarios, para poder acceder los valores, pero no sé como hacerlo.

Probé usando un for loop y creando una lista con las "keys" del primer diccionario adentro para volverlo a descomponer, y al parecer al hacer eso ya deja de ser un diccionario las "keys", también probé en descomponer todo de una pero no podía acceder a los valores, soy muy nuevo en programación así que no estoy seguro de que hacer, conozco un método para hacerlo pero es muy largo y manual, y quisiera ver si es posible hacerlo usando *for*.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

**Edición:**
Debido a tu comentario me parece que hace falta explicar un poco más

En tu caso, `products` es un diccionario, puedes identificar los diccionarios porque usan `{}` al declarar los elementos que estáran dentro del diccionario, también tienen "llaves" es decir, nombres que puedes utilizar para acceder la información, en tu caso `products` tiene la llave `mobiles` y la llave `laptops`

Una lista se declara utilizando `[]` y para acceder a los elementos internos debes utilizar el número de índice del elemento que deseas acceder, en tu caso el nivel de marca (Por ejemplo Apple) es una lista. Los índices de las listas empiezan con `0` por lo que si quisieras ver la información del "iPhone 7" tendrías que hacer lo siguiente

```
products['mobiles']['Apple'][0]
```

El `0` es porque es el primer elemento de la lista dentro de "Apple"

Ahora, si quieres obtener el nombre del teléfono, por ejemplo "iPhone 7" entonces haces lo siguiente:

```
products['mobiles']['Apple'][0]['name']
```

La estructura que tienes en `products` es:

1. Diccionario de tipo de dispositivo
2. Diccionario de marca
3. Lista de productos
4. Diccionario con la descripción de producto

Entonces para resumir, accedemos a un diccionario por medio del nombre de su llave (Por ejemplo `mobiles` o `laptops`) y accedemos a una lista por medio del índice del elemento (Por ejemplo `0` ó `1`) dependiendo de la posición del elemento, tomando en cuenta que las listas siempre inician con `0`

**Respuesta original:**

Puedes recorrer el diccionario con bucles `for`, necesitas un `for` para cada nivel

```
products = {
    "mobiles": {
        "Apple": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "iPhone 7",
                "price": 300
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "iPhone 8",
                "price": 350
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "iPhone Xr",
                "price": 450
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "iPhone Xs",
                "price": 460
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "iPhone 11",
                "price": 900
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "iPhone 12",
                "price": 1100
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "iPhone 13",
                "price": 1300
            },
        ],
        "Samsung": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy Beam",
                "price": 150
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S6",
                "price": 200
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S7",
                "price": 300
            },
        ],
        "Xiaomi": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8",
                "price": 250
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro",
                "price": 300
            },
        ]
    },
    "laptops": {
        "DELL": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Dell Inspiron 15",
                "price": 600
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Dell Latitude 14",
                "price": 650
            },
        ],
        "MAC": [
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "MacBook Pro 13",
                "price": 900
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "MacBook M1",
                "price": 1500
            },
        ]
    },
}

for elemento in products:
  for marca in products[elemento]:
    for producto in products[elemento][marca]:
      print(elemento, ' --> ', marca, ' --> ', producto)
```

Esto te devuelve lo siguiente:

```
mobiles  -->  Apple  -->  {'id': 1, 'name': 'iPhone 7', 'price': 300}
mobiles  -->  Apple  -->  {'id': 2, 'name': 'iPhone 8', 'price': 350}
mobiles  -->  Apple  -->  {'id': 3, 'name': 'iPhone Xr', 'price': 450}
mobiles  -->  Apple  -->  {'id': 4, 'name': 'iPhone Xs', 'price': 460}
mobiles  -->  Apple  -->  {'id': 5, 'name': 'iPhone 11', 'price': 900}
mobiles  -->  Apple  -->  {'id': 6, 'name': 'iPhone 12', 'price': 1100}
mobiles  -->  Apple  -->  {'id': 7, 'name': 'iPhone 13', 'price': 1300}
mobiles  -->  Samsung  -->  {'id': 8, 'name': 'Samsung Galaxy Beam', 'price': 150}
mobiles  -->  Samsung  -->  {'id': 9, 'name': 'Samsung Galaxy S6', 'price': 200}
mobiles  -->  Samsung  -->  {'id': 10, 'name': 'Samsung Galaxy S7', 'price': 300}
mobiles  -->  Xiaomi  -->  {'id': 11, 'name': 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 8', 'price': 250}
mobiles  -->  Xiaomi  -->  {'id': 12, 'name': 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro', 'price': 300}
laptops  -->  DELL  -->  {'id': 13, 'name': 'Dell Inspiron 15', 'price': 600}
laptops  -->  DELL  -->  {'id': 14, 'name': 'Dell Latitude 14', 'price': 650}
laptops  -->  MAC  -->  {'id': 15, 'name': 'MacBook Pro 13', 'price': 900}
laptops  -->  MAC  -->  {'id': 16, 'name': 'MacBook M1', 'price': 1500}
```

Comment: Ahora con todos esos for, ¿como hago para seleccionar por ejemplo un valor especifico? por ejemplo quiero que solo me muestre la línea:

laptops  -->  DELL  -->  {'id': 14, 'name': 'Dell Latitude 14', 'price': 650}

¿Como haría?

Comment: Para acceder a un valor en específico puedes utilizar las llaves de tus diccionarios `print(products['laptops']['DELL'][1])` ten en cuenta que a nivel de la marca tienes una lista de diccionarios, por eso el número 1

Comment: me refería a los valores finales, los diccionarios que están dentro de la lista, son a los que no logro acceder y necesito
Disculpa la molestia

Comment: Esos sería de la siguiente forma: `products['laptops']['DELL'][1]['name']` Acabo de editar mi respuesta con más detalles porque pienso que te hace falta entender la diferencia entre diccionarios y listas y como acceder a cada uno de ellos

Comment: Muchas gracias, en serio